# Objective C: Using '%' Operator With Doubles

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math, operator-keyword

I had an interesting problem today. As part of practice with my fluency with objective-c, as I sit in math class, I write programs for each problem done on the board in hopes to increase my math and programming capabilities.

However, today I encountered a problem. One of the questions was something like "Find the greatest prime number that 10564245 (<-- example number) is divisible by"

So, I went in and made the program. I got as far as doing the loop for values to check, and then began to code the part where it checks the reminder, and if it's 0, it logs it, and if it isn't, it skips it.

However, since the number is too big to be an `int`, it had to be a `double`. When I tried to plug the number in, the program gave me errors when I wanted to use the `%` operator with the double. Is there any way to find remainders if you have a very large number?

Thanks

ERROR: `Invalid operands to binary expression`

EDIT: SOLVED!

I took a little from each answer. We have the fmod capability, but I ended up using `long` instead of `int`, I don't know why I didn't think of the origionally

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and the exact error you receive?

Comment: You can use [`long`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Long_integer) or `long long` instead of `double`. Also, what is the value that you consider as too big to be an `int`?

Comment: @JTApps: That error is useless without the line(s) of code generating that error. Just post a small code sample.

Comment: 10564245 is well within the bounds of an int, on My Mac, an integer is 32 bits, and the max value is 2147483647.

Comment: You can also use an `unsigned`, to get up to a whopping 4 billion possible numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double values aren't precise for integer values and so probably shouldn't be used for this sort of thing.  Instead, you can use a long into or even a long long int to do your calculations

Comment: @JTApps So why'd you give the other guy the answer, then? ;)

Comment: Good point. I forgot a lot of the data types back from my Java days. I should've remembered something as easy as longs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use fmod().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double a = 77879878978942312315687897;
    double b = 10;
    printf("%.f",fmod(a, b));
}
```

Comment: I've never actually learned that before. Could you provide a syntax example/log? It would help me greatly.

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately, if he's looking for prime factors, this will most likely leave trailing decimal values, making a comparison against zero likely to give false negatives for his context

Comment: @JRaymond That's what I was going for here